# Detect whether a specific user account exists during install

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm using a wix installer which should be able to detect a specific windows user account during the installation. So when I try to install and if the user does not exist in that machine means it should not proceed further. Is it possible in wix?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a custom action which to checks for the user, if found set a `property`. Make this custom action run before `LaunchConditions` e.g. `<Custom Action="Your_CA" Before="LaunchConditions" />` and in the Launch Conditions check for that property.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Since I'm new to wix, it would be great if you provide custom action to check for specific user or provide me some URL.

Comment: You can create custom action in Managed Code as well as Unmanaged (c++)code, these links guides you to create a custom action in both types of code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335516/Custom-Action-in-Visual-Studio-setup-projects http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132918/Creating-Custom-Action-for-WIX-Written-in-Managed

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make sure that user exists, you could just use the [util:User](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_user.htm) element to create the user as part of the install:

```
<util:User Id="UserToCheckOrCreate"
           Name="User123"
           Password="Pa55w0rd"
           CreateUser="yes"
           UpdateIfExists="yes"
           PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
           PasswordExpired="no"
           RemoveOnUninstall="yes" />
```